# Performance of Prime Testing with Haskell

Tags: algorithm, performance, haskell, primes

I have two ways of testing for primes. One of them called `isPrime` and the other is `isBigPrime`. What I originally wanted is to test "big" primes with "small" primes that I have already computed, so that the testing becomes faster. Here are my implementations:

```
intSqrt :: Integer -> Integer
intSqrt n = round $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n

isPrime' :: Integer->Integer -> Bool
isPrime' 1 m = False
isPrime' n m = do
  if (m > (intSqrt n))
    then True
    else if (rem n (m+1) == 0)
         then False
         else do isPrime' n (m+1)

isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime 2 = True
isPrime 3 = True
isPrime n = isPrime' n 1
isBigPrime' :: Integer ->Int ->Bool
isBigPrime' n i =
  if ( ( smallPrimes !! i ) > intSqrt n )
  then True
  else if (rem n (smallPrimes !! i) == 0)
       then False
       else do isBigPrime' n (i+1)
smallPrimes = [2,3, List of Primes until 1700]
--Start at 1 because we only go through uneven numbers
isBigPrime n = isBigPrime' n 1
primes m = [2]++[k | k <- [3,5..m], isPrime k]
bigPrimes m = smallPrimes ++ [k | k <- [1701,1703..m], isBigPrime k]
main = do
  print $ (sum $ [Enter Method] 2999999 )
```

I have chosen 1700 as upper limit because I wanted to have primes up to 3e6 and sqrt(3e6) ~ 1700. I took the sum of them to compare those two algorithms. I thought that `bigPrimes` would be way faster that `primes` because first of all it does way less calculations *and* it has a head start, which is not too big but anyway. However to my surprise `bigPrimes` was slower than `primes`. Here are the results:

For `primes`

```
Performance counter stats for './p10':


      16768,627686      task-clock (msec)         #    1,000 CPUs utilized          
                58      context-switches          #    0,003 K/sec                  
                 1      cpu-migrations            #    0,000 K/sec                  
             6.496      page-faults               #    0,387 K/sec                  
    53.416.641.157      cycles                    #    3,186 GHz                    
   <not supported>      stalled-cycles-frontend  
   <not supported>      stalled-cycles-backend   
   160.411.056.099      instructions              #    3,00  insns per cycle        
    34.512.352.987      branches                  # 2058,150 M/sec                  
        10.673.742      branch-misses             #    0,03% of all branches        

      16,773316435 seconds time elapsed
```

and for `bigPrimes`

```
 Performance counter stats for './p10':

      19111,667046      task-clock (msec)         #    0,999 CPUs utilized          
               259      context-switches          #    0,014 K/sec                  
                 3      cpu-migrations            #    0,000 K/sec                  
             6.278      page-faults               #    0,328 K/sec                  
    61.027.453.425      cycles                    #    3,193 GHz                    
   <not supported>      stalled-cycles-frontend  
   <not supported>      stalled-cycles-backend   
   198.207.905.034      instructions              #    3,25  insns per cycle        
    34.632.138.061      branches                  # 1812,094 M/sec                  
       106.102.114      branch-misses             #    0,31% of all branches        

      19,126843560 seconds time elapsed
```

I was wondering why that would be the case. I am suspecting that using `primes!!n` makes `bigPrimes` somewhat slower but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: From looking at your statistics the biggest difference that jumps out to me is ```branch-misses```. Your function for small primes has ```10.673.742      branch-misses             #    0,03% of all branches``` and your function for big primes has ```106.102.114      branch-misses             #    0,31% of all branches```. Your big primes function mis-predicts branches 10x as much as your small primes function. That could cause you some slowdown. Although, the miss rate is small enough even for the big primes that it probably isn't the whole story

Comment: If you are just interested in checking whether a particular number is a prime, there are far better methods. look up Rabin-Miller, for example

Comment: "p is greater than the square root of n" is equivalent to "the square of p is greater than n", however, the latter one needs only integer multiplication and comparison, whereas the former one requires much more CPU work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common antipattern brought from other languages is to iterate over indices and use `(!!)` to index into a list. In Haskell, it is instead idiomatic to simply iterate over the list itself. So:

```
isBigPrime' :: Integer -> [Integer] ->Bool
isBigPrime' n [] = True
isBigPrime' n (p:ps) = p > intSqrt n || (rem n p /= 0 && isBigPrime' n ps)

isBigPrime n = isBigPrime' n (drop 1 smallPrimes)
```

On my machine, your `primes` takes 25.3s; your `bigPrimes` takes 20.9s; and my `bigPrimes` takes 3.2s. There are several other pieces of low-hanging fruit (e.g. using `p*p > n` instead of `p > intSqrt n`), but this is by far the most significant one.

Comment: Very neat! This should change my way of Haskell programming. I'm still new to it. Though I wonder why `!!` is so slow.

Comment: @gonenc `(!!)` is slow because it is the naive O(n) indexing operation into a linked list.